# bash grep rows inside single file older than X days

Tags: bash

I'm building a bash script to check all rows inside local file older than X days.
I have this file:

```
ANDREA_20231002_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231005_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231009_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231011_020004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231012_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231012_210002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231013_060003_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
```

I should generate a new file to view only rows older than two day/three from today.
For example, if today is **20231014** I should view all rows from **20231002** to **20231011**.
I have created this script but is not correct because I see only lines older than two days but not those older:

```
yesterday="`date +%Y%m%d --date="-2 day"`"
cat myfile | grep $yesterday
```

can you help me, please :-)

Comment: Hi Paolo, In my example, if today is 20231014 the new list should contain only row from 20231011 to 20231002... the new file should contain row 20231002, 20231005, 20231009, 20231011...

Comment: @foscolino ok I provided an answer that gives that

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: I realized that and my answer is similar to what you state. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU AWK

```
$ awk -F_ -v x=2 '
    BEGIN{
        print "today is", strftime("%Y%m%d")
        date = strftime("%Y%m%d",systime()-(x*60*60*24))
    }
    $2 < date 
' file

today is 20231014
ANDREA_20231002_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231005_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231009_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231011_020004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk` for this:

```bash
$ v=20231014
$ awk -v var="$v" -F"_" '(var-$2)>2' file
ANDREA_20231002_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231005_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231009_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231011_020004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

So you apparently want to exclude today, yesterday and the day before. As suggested in another answer `awk` would probably be a better choice for this but as you started with `grep` here is what you could do. You can search for one or another pattern with `grep -E '(pattern1|pattern2)'` and you can print only the non-matching lines with `-v`. So, you could compute variables `t`, `y` and `d` (for today, yesterday and the day before) and `grep -Ev "($t|$y|$d)" myfile`:

```
t=_$(date +%Y%m%d)_
y=_$(date +%Y%m%d --date="-1 day")_
d=_$(date +%Y%m%d --date="-2 day")_
grep -Ev "($t|$y|$d)" myfile
```

Note: `cat myfile | grep 'regex'` is the very common [UUOC anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). Simply `grep 'regex' myfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are 1) trying to resolve a range vs a simple match and 2) matching a value that *may* be between two values, your best bet is somthing that allows *numeric* comparisons on the date field rather than trying to construct a regex. That rules out `sed`, `grep` and point to `awk`, `ruby`, `perl` or `python` as the best way to do this.

Consider the file:

```
$ cat file
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
```

Now suppose you want to print lines with the regex value of `/4/,/11/` (something you would do with `sed`) Since there is no `4`, the first part of your range never matches and nothing is printed.

Instead suppose you do that numerically with `awk`. It is trivial:

```
$ awk '$1>=4 && $1<=11' file 
5
7
9
11
```

This same logic applies you your case. Instead of trying to use `grep` with a regex, match the date fields numerically. Suppose you want the *range* of dates between `20231003` and `20231011` (chosen to eliminate the first line of the example) it is trivial:

```
awk  -F "_" '$2>=20231003 && $2<=20231011' your_file
ANDREA_20231005_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231009_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231011_020004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
```

If you just want all lines prior to 'day before yesterday':

```
awk  -F "_" -v d="$(date +%Y%m%d)" '$2<=(d-2)' your_file
ANDREA_20231002_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231005_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231009_050004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
ANDREA_20231011_020004_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.txt
```

Comment: hi dawg, thank for your support, your solution is very good! thanks